# DataGrid: strange column autosizing behavior on data change

Tags: wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

A column with `Width="*"` does not shrink automatically when the adjacent column with `Width="Auto"` expands due to its data change.

I want to show in DataGrid a list of objects with three properties (from left to right):

- LongString
- ShortString1
- ShortString2

All columns should be visible: LongString data can be truncated whereas `ShortString1` and `ShortString2` should be displayed fully.

So I define the columns in XAML with the following widths:

- LongString: "*"
- ShortString1: "Auto"
- ShortString2: "Auto"

Initially everything is ok, but when the value in the middle column becomes longer, the rightmost column slips out of the window (I expect that the leftmost column would shrink as its width is "*").

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="DataGridColumnWidthIssue.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="250" Width="400">
    <DockPanel>
        <Button Name="modifyButton" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                Padding="30,5,30,5" Click="modifyButton_Click">
            Modify
        </Button>
        <DataGrid Name="infoGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Infos}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Long String" Binding="{Binding LongString}" Width="*"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Short String 1" Binding="{Binding ShortString1}" Width="Auto"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Short String 2" Binding="{Binding ShortString2}" Width="Auto"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Code-behind:

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;

namespace DataGridColumnWidthIssue
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Info> Infos { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Info>();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Infos.Add(new Info("Veeeeeeeeery looooooooooooong striiiiiiiiiiiiiing", "Short string 1", "Short string 2"));
            DataContext = this;
        }

        private void modifyButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Infos[0].ShortString1 += "AA";
        }
    }

    public class Info : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public string LongString { get; }

        string shortString1;
        public string ShortString1
        {
            get { return shortString1; }
            set
            {
                if (value != shortString1)
                {
                    shortString1 = value;
                    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ShortString1"));
                }
            }
        }

        public string ShortString2 { get; }

        public Info(string longString, string shortString1, string shortString2)
        {
            LongString = longString;
            ShortString1 = shortString1;
            ShortString2 = shortString2;
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
}
```

**Step 1. Run the program.**

The result is as expected: all columns are visible.

[Screenshot (good 1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGps1.jpg)

**Step 2. Press twice the "Modify" button** at the bottom of the window. (It adds "AA" to the middle column property (`ShortString1`) value.)

What I expect:

- LongString column shrinks
- ShortString1 column stretches
- ShortString2 column remains unchanged

[Screenshot (good 2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAgDX.jpg)

What actually happens:

- LongString column remains unchanged
- ShortString1 column stretches
- ShortString2 column moves right and gets partially out of visibility

[Screenshot (bad 1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQssk.jpg)

**Step 3. Press "Modify" 3 more times.** The `ShortString2` is almost completely out of the window.

[Screenshot (bad 2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fcu30.jpg)

An interesting detail is that after maximizing and restoring the window the column widths become as expected.

**UPDATE:** UpdateLayout() after the data change has no effect (tried both for the window and for the grid)

**Step 4. Maximize and restore the window**

[Screenshot (good 3)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0rB1.jpg)

Is this behavior correct?

Are there workarounds to get the expected behavior?

Thanks for any help.

Target framework: 4.7.2.

Comment: you say maximizing and restoring the window fixes your issue. Maybe all that this is doing is caling the UpdateLayout? try doing this manually

Comment: I've tried and it has no effect. Sorry for not mentioning it.

Comment: Maciej S: Thanks for your editing